# OnClick event not firing for radio button in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, onclick, radio-button

I have a a couple radio buttons that render fine in IE7-IE10. When I am using IE9-IE10 doc standards with the debugger, all the javascript and html works just fine. But when I am using IE7/8 doc standards, the onClick event doesnt fire. I try using the debugger and add in breakpoints at the start of the javascript functions that should be called with the onClick event but the js never gets called because the radio button onClick event doesnt fire. Why does this only happen in IE7/8 and how can I get the onClick event to fire in IE7/8?

EDIT:
None of the `<input>` types fire their events in IE7/8. Could I be missing opening or closing tags or something simple? Everything works fine in IE9/10, why does it not work in 7/8?

```
<td valign=top colspan=2>
<FONT class='GroupText'><b>Apply Location:</b>
<input type='radio' name='ApplyLocation' value='1' onClick='changeForm(1);changeSave(1);' checked>&nbsp;Search Locations&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='radio' name='ApplyLocation' onClick='changeForm(0);changeSave(0);' value='0'>&nbsp;New Location
</FONT></td>
```

Comment: You're using IE10 to test your code in older IEs? Not reliable. Anyway, remove all console-stuff and try with an old-fashion alert.

Comment: I tried that.. alert only fires under the same circumstances as stated originally.

Comment: @kascheri12 can you post the code for changeForm() and changeSave()? The problem might be somewhere in the functions.

Comment: Its not in the functions, the functions dont even get called in IE7/8. When I remove the function calls and replace them with a simple alert() function for onClick, the alert() window doesnt pop up in IE7/8 but does pop up in IE9/10.

Similarly, the function calls work in IE9/10 but not in IE7/8.

Comment: @kascheri12 does changing onClick to onChange make a difference?

Comment: Nope, it doesnt make a difference. I get the same problems with the same IE versions.

Comment: Whoa! Somebody's using a font tag!